# MySQL query for check alerts during a timelapse and condition

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-range

Hello I have next table:

```
EventID     datetime                        value
1           2012-12-15 12:45:06             15.3
2           2012-12-15 13:00:06             16.9
3           2012-12-15 13:15:06             17.3
4           2012-12-15 13:30:06             16.9
5           2012-12-15 13:45:06             18.8
6           2012-12-15 14:00:06             21.3
7           2012-12-15 14:15:06             21.9
9           2012-12-15 14:30:06             22.7
10          2012-12-15 14:45:06             23.2
11          2012-12-15 15:00:06             23.6
```

And the conditions are:

`value>=15` and `value<=20` and this condition must be for a one HOUR or more continuous

for this set of data, query must show (count):

```
1
```

alert, corresponding to events ID `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

I try with:

`select * from events where value>=15 and value<=`20

but I dont know how I detect a continuous range of one Hour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot reliably do this from SQL. Scrape the relevant results in a programming language like PHP or C# and detect the contiguousness there.

Comment: @Mihai, the same, doesnt work

Comment: Not contiguous @Mihai

Comment: That's a complicated and quite expensive query. Have you considered using a trigger?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yes, but the same problem, I have to remember first time when the condition starts and check if next 15 minutes this is into the interval.

Comment: The table ty triggered an insert to would do remember for you. It's not trivial, but you run a query to get this sort of results while you are collecting data, you could end up with a number of issues.

Comment: Recommend create an application to process those datas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM
(
  SELECT 1
    FROM
  (
    SELECT *, 
           @n := @n + 1 rnum, 
           @g := IF(value BETWEEN 15 AND 20, @g + 1, 1) grnum, 
           @p := value
      FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @p := NULL, @g := 0) i
     ORDER BY datetime
  ) q
   GROUP BY rnum - grnum
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
     AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MIN(datetime), MAX(datetime)) >= 1
) p
```

Output:

```
| TOTAL |
|-------|
|     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf2b8/8)** demo

Answer (score 0):

A solution using triggers

Assuming you are inserting in the events table and always at the current and only one process is doing it.

If you create a table called say transitions

```
TransitionID StartTime, EndTime
```

Then in a insert trigger on the events table

```
If the value >= 15 and <= 20
  If the Transitions table is empty or the last record has an endtime 
  create a new record with the startTime of the event

If the value < 15 or > 20
  if the Transitions table is not empty and the last record has no endtime
    if an hour has passed update the endtime 
    if it hasn't delete the last transition record
```